# Integer cannot be cast to Float

Tags: java, mongodb, bukkit

Currently I am working a plugin that involves saying locations in the database, and then caching them `onEnable()`. However, I run into this error - "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Float" when I try and phrase a location. Here is my phrase method:

```
 private HubLocation formatLocation(DBObject object){
    World world = Bukkit.getWorld((String)object.get("world"));
    Location location = new Location(world, (double)object.get("x"), (double)object.get("y"), (double)object.get("z"),
            (float)object.get("yaw"), (float)object.get("pitch"));
    return new HubLocation((String)object.get("name"), location);
}
```

Hope someone can help, 
Thanks!

Comment: You can't promote an int to float type, also shouldn't the title be edited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common issue with MonogDB doing strange type conversions. The safest solution is to always use the Number type for values from the database:

```
private HubLocation formatLocation(DBObject object){
    World world = Bukkit.getWorld(object.get("world").toString());
    Location location = new Location(world, 
        ((Number)object.get("x")).doubleValue(), 
        ((Number)object.get("y")).doubleValue(), 
        ((Number)object.get("z")).doubleValue(),
        ((Number)object.get("yaw")).floatValue(), 
        ((Number)object.get("pitch")).floatValue());
    return new HubLocation(object.get("name").toString(), location);
}
```